# Must I create a mapping relationship between two entities in hibernate?

Tags: spring, hibernate, orm

For example, if you have an order table in Hibernate and a product table that receives an order, it is mapped as a one to many relationship.Then,Must I write the mapping relationship in code here? In my project, I permanently store order information in a database I have, but in that case, does it need to be a mapping relationship?There's nothing else to do except delete cascade i think.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the association in your business code, you also need to model in your domain model. In the described example, I would expect a many-to-many association between the Order and the Product entity. You could model it as a uni- (= only on 1 entity) or bidirectional (= on both entities) association.

Here is a quick example. I provide a very detailed description of all kinds of associations in my [guide to association mappings](https://thorben-janssen.com/ultimate-guide-association-mappings-jpa-hibernate/).

```
public class Order {

   @ManyToMany
   private Set<Product> products;

   ...
}

public class Product {

   @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "products")
   private Set<Order> orders;

   ...
}
```